# Runtime bytecode not contained in creation bytecode

Tags: evm, assembly, bytecode, deployed-bytecode, creationcode

I'm currently delving into EVM and contract bytecode.
My understanding is that by sending a transaction to the NULL address with both the initcode and contract code, and ensuring that the init code returns the contract code (runtime code) in the final instruction, a contract with an initialized state is created.

Given that my creation code (initcode + runtimecode) includes the runtimecode, I would expect that once my contract is deployed, its runtime code would be contained within the input data of the transaction that created the contract.

To validate my comprehension, I attempted to inspect the contract of a project I like, but I seem to be overlooking something.

**Contract creation:**

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3b8ad64a25f39773d5fa4ce5c167414ade5d2d9b4edd98f69c04240060224675

In this transaction, the contract is created using the CREATE2 opcode, utilizing the contract `0x4e59b44847b379578588920cA78FbF26c0B4956C`. Clicking on "more details" allows for viewing the input data sent to this contract.

**Created contract:**

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1bbe973bef3a977fc51cbed703e8ffdefe001fed#code

Here is the resulting contract. By examining the `Contract Creation Code` section, I discovered precisely the same data present in the input data section of the preceding transaction (minus 32 bytes, which are used as salt for the create2 opcode).

**Runtime bytecode:**

So far so good: the input data matched the `Contract Creation Code`. Therefore, I expected the `Deployed Bytecode` section of Etherscan to display the same bytecode as the `Contract Creation Code`, minus the constructor and constructor parameters.

However, upon comparison, some discrepancies emerged:

[image: Differences between creation and runtime bytecode]

As you can see, a lot of zeros present in the creation code are replaced with some other data in the runtime bytecode.

I cannot wrap my head around this.

Can you help me to understand this behaviour?
I thought that some kind of optimization kicked in to use free spaces (zeros) but I cannot understand how... the compile phase is before submitting the transaction, not after.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy a contract the EVM executes the constructor's bytecode. Usually the constructor initializes the contract storage and returns the contract's runtime bytecode, but that isn't required.

Recent version of solc implemented the `immutables` variables. Those variables behave like `constant` variables after they are initialized.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.25/contracts.html#immutable

> The contract creation code generated by the compiler will modify the contract’s runtime code before it is returned by replacing all references to `immutables` with the values assigned to them.

In general the constructor isn't required to include the runtime bytecode. It could generate it during the execution.

Comment: Thank you! That could be a valid explanation!
I just don't understand one last thing: I have compiled che contract with Remix and I'm able to reproduce 100% of the creation code, even the CBOR section with IPFS hash, but if I go to "compilation details"->"Runtime bytecode", remix shows me a different runtime bytecode. It shows me the creation minus constructor. Is that a bug? Shouldn't shows me what is really on chain?
I mark your answer as the solution btw, thank you again!

Comment: Ok, I'll answer myself: it's normal that remix shows runtime bytecode without the immutables applied, since some immutables could depends from constructor parameters.
Moreover I verified that all the modification that I have on the runtime bytecode are related to immutables.